# Oracle sql select query returns id that not mach to where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have query that is working fine if the id have one or many rows out of data range. But if the id have for example 2 rows - first out of date range and the second in data range the query returns me this id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT na.public_id
  FROM na_agent_cients na
  JOIN tt_call cc
  ON na.public_id=cc.primary_contact_id
  WHERE cc.call_date NOT BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('13/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

So for example if i have one id and this id have two rows first with date 05/09/2016 and second row with date 11/09/2016 the query returns me this id and that`s wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ID exists in a row that **is** in the date range, so it should be returned. If you want to exclude all the IDs that appear in rows outside of your range you could do so with the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT na.public_id
FROM   na_agent_cients na
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   tt_call cc
                   WHERE  na.public_id = cc.primary_contact_id AND
                          cc.call_date NOT BETWEEN 
                                       TO_DATE('10/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
                                       TO_DATE('13/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `Group by` and `Having` clause.

Move the condition to `having` clause and count only when condition is not met to pull the `public_id` only when all the rows are not falling between the given date range.

```
SELECT na.public_id
FROM   na_agent_cients na
       JOIN tt_call cc
         ON na.public_id = cc.primary_contact_id
GROUP  BY na.public_id
HAVING sum(CASE
               WHEN cc.call_date NOT BETWEEN To_date('10/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND To_date('13/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') THEN 0 else 1
             END) = 0
```